# How to display database contain in paragraph wise in html

Tags: php, sql

In database, I have one field namely description. In description field, Lot's of content which is paragraph wise. 
for example, 
Description field

This is a line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 --------- line 1

This is a line 2 line 2 line 2 line 2 line 2 --------- line 2

In line 2 have a space between line 1 or 2  in database ok. Now I want to display as it is line in html. Then, how I will execute.

I will try this for retrive my description  field from database

```
  <p><?php echo $row["description"];?></p>
```

Using this I get description field data but not in para wise content it is in all in one line.

For example :This is a line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 --------- line 1This is a line 2 line 2 line 2 line 2 line 2 --------- line 2

but I want spacing. Any one help me. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Try with `nl2br()` function echo nl2br($row["description"]);

Comment: thank you for your answer. It will work thank you so much ma'am @Nidhi

Comment: please post your answer so I will give vote or upmark it is useful answer @Nidhi

Comment: Oh....I post my answer...@android-developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy..

use 'n2blr` function.

```
The nl2br() function inserts HTML line breaks (<br> or <br />) in front of each newline (\n) in a string.
```

Write your code like this :

`echo nl2br($row["description"]);`

See [demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pcbx-p6yd) for understand it well

Answer (score 0):

In which format you are saving data to the database? Try to Save as HTML format and while retrieving get content and display.Instead of just showing in

tag.

For ex:Description inside the database should be like 

test 123
  hello test

. If you are saving in this format for sure data output will come as HTML format.